# WordPress Search Filter based on checkbox field values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a food blog running and I want to add to my website a filter search, where users can select attributes of a recipe and then a list of fitting recipes is showing, based on the attributes. Example attributes:

- sourdough
- yeast
- wheat
- rye
- spelt
- easy recipe
- expert recipe
- fast recipe
- bake in the morning
- bake in the evening
- high hydration
- low hydration
  ...

The user shall select all recipe attributes and then in the end a list of posts with title, name, excerpt, image and link shall be shown.

Are there already existing solutions for that? I have problems finding them. Or ideas on how to solve this by code?

Thanks for your support
René